# bootstrap samples by row of a data frame in r

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, weighted-average

I am trying to run a simple bootstrap on the rows of a data frame in r. Here is what I have worked up so far, but I'm hitting a dead end.

```
x1 <- c(1:5)
x2 <- c(6:10)
y <- runif(5)
z <- as.data.frame(rbind(x1, x2, y))

trial <- 10
avg <- rep(0, trial)
for(i in 1:trial){
  ind <- sample(ncol(z), size = ncol(z), replace = TRUE)
  z.boot <- z[ind, ]
  mean[i] <- mean(z.boot)
}
mean
```

Ideally, what I would like to do is to get a bootstrap weighted mean for the first and second rows with the weights in the third row but I can't even get my loop to work. There has to be a better way to do this. Any help is appreciated

Comment: You sample from `ncol(z)`, but then you subset by row. You also try to find the `mean` of a `data.frame` (which is not defined). What are you trying to do?

Comment: I suppose another option would be to sample using the weights as probabilities and looking for the median. Really, I'm just trying to learn this technique as applied to rows of a data frame.

Answer (score 0):

try this... I don't quite get your point about weighted mean... but you can maybe work it out from here:

```
n= seq( 100, 500, 50)    
bootdata=list()
for (i in 1:length(n)) {
   bootdata[[i]]=data[sample(nrow(data), n[i], replace=TRUE), ]
}
bootdata
str(bootdata[[1]])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is how a non-parametric bootstrap could be done. (This seems to be the type you are trying to do, based on your code.) Please note that `nrow()` and not the `ncol()` is the proper function. Bootstraps which are stored as items of the list "bootResult" could be retrieved via their index, like `bootResult[[2]]` and go through the next steps:

```
  nBoots<-10 #number of bootstraps
  bootResult<-list()
  for (i in seq_len(nBoots)){
    bootResult[[i]]<-z[sample(seq_len(nrow(z)), nrow(z), replace=TRUE), ]
  }
```