# Apply boot() by row of a data frame in r

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap

I have a dataframe:

```
df <- structure(list(Gene = c("Dleu2", "Ano3", "Shisa2", "Cox6b2", 
"Ccnd3", "Tnfsf9", "Nynrin", "Pid1", "Cd200r1", "Syde1"), `condition-cKOvsaFL.FC` = c(2.483219034, 
2.276983629, 2.233439806, 2.133677932, 2.092328446, 2.047418548, 
2.018261269, 1.978336246, 1.967370561, 1.956986235), `condition-cKOvsaFL.RawP` = c(7.62e-33, 
NA, 1.28e-10, 1.03e-14, 2e-38, 1.18e-12, NA, 3.7e-07, 2.55e-17, 
6.07e-07), Sum = c(32, 0, 1, 9, 96, 480, 0, 0, 78, 6)), .Names = c("Gene", 
"condition-cKOvsaFL.FC", "condition-cKOvsaFL.RawP", "Sum"), row.names = c(762L, 
197L, 2431L, 636L, 468L, 2838L, 1821L, 1963L, 485L, 2655L), class = "data.frame")
```

and would like to apply bootstrapping to this data frame by row. I have a function that works when used with boot() to calculate the ratio of genes that are have condition-cKOvsaFL.FC > 1 based on the subset of genes that have a Sum >= j. j here would be the variable that would be described by each row of the data frame (i.e., for each row, I would like the boot() function to substitute the value of 'Sum' for that row in for j)

```
function.ratio_up_bootstrap <- function(j,d,i)
{
d <- subset(d, `Sum` >= j)
d2 <- d[i,]
d.up = subset(d2,
          `condition-cKOvsaFL.RawP` <= 0.05 &
            `condition-cKOvsaFL.FC` >1)
all = d2
return(nrow(d.up) /nrow(d))
}
```

I have gotten this boot() function to work by substituting a value in for j manually but would like to be able to apply this to every single row in my data frame (which is thousands of rows).

```
b1 = boot(data=df, function.ratio_up_bootstrap, R=50, stype = 'i', j=32)
b2 = boot(data=df, function.ratio_up_bootstrap, R=50, stype = 'i', j=0)
b3 = boot(data=df, function.ratio_up_bootstrap, R=50, stype = 'i', j=1)
```

and then I would like to calculate boot.ci() confidence intervals for each of these boot() calls and plot them using ggplot2.

I have been trying to do this using apply() and lapply() but have been unable to get it to work. Thanks in advance!

p.s.
I have seen the post [bootstrap samples by row of a data frame in r](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40233902/bootstrap-samples-by-row-of-a-data-frame-in-r) but it is using a for loop with a list and I was unable to figure out how to apply it to my own problem. I am very new to R so answers accounting for that would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Can't you just do `lapply(df$Sum, function(x) boot(..., j=x))`?

Comment: I'm not sure...could you fill that out more completely? I'm not sure I understand how to fill in that line of code so that it would work with what I have. would I replace "function(x)" with "function.ratio_up_bootstrap(x)"? And what would go in the "boot(...,)"? Thanks!

Comment: Sorry - the `...` was meant to mean the stuff you have in your question - i.e. `data=df, function.ratio_up_bootstrap, R=50, stype = 'i'`.  The `function(x)` bit is defining an internal function (`boot(...)`) which `lapply` runs through for each value of `df$Sum`, so `x` here is where it substitutes the values it is running through.  The output will be a list of bootstrap outputs.

Comment: Thanks for clarifying. I tried `lapply(df_test$Gene, function(x) boot(data=df_test, function.ratio_up_bootstrap, R=50, stype = 'i', j=x))` but it  does not seem to be using the value in the Sum column to replace j since I get the message "WARNING: All values of t1* are NA" for every line...any ideas?

Comment: oops, realized i was using df$Gene rather than df$Sum. Thank you, this script worked as expected!